# Naming convention used for Cloud Foundry Ops Manager URL?

Tags: cloud-foundry

When setting up Cloud Foundry, there are naming conventions for setting up the system and application domains:

- *.system.[somedomain.com]
- *.apps.[somedomain.com]

I haven't found any similar recommendations for naming the ops manager though.  Looking online, there seems to be several variations:

- ops.[somedomain.com]
- opsmgr.[somedomain.com]
- opsman.[somedomain.com]
- opsmanager.[somedomain.com]
- etc.

For those who see many Cloud Foundry installations, what is the most commonly used name?

Comment: please refere the link, this may resolve your query 
 https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely a point of personal preference, or perhaps company preference.  The only requirement for Ops Manager is that you use an FQDN to access it (technically you can get away using an IP, but it's not a good practice because IPs can change and that will cause problems).

That said, we use the pattern `opsmgr-XX.example.com`, `run-XX.example.com` as the system domain and `cfapps-XX.example.com` as the apps domain, where XX is a two digit number, in the lab of 25 PCF installations I help manage.

Hope that helps!